# Proguard obfuscation removes type

Tags: android, serialization, obfuscation, proguard, simple-framework

After running Proguard using obfuscation, I get the following error:

```
Could not find type for field 'significantEvents' private java.util.HashMap com.fsr.tracker.PersistedState.significantEvents at index 1
```

This error occurs in the following code where I am using a simpleXML serializer to serialize an object (`persistedState`):

```
Serializer serializer = new Persister(new DateMatcher());
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream  = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
serializer.write(persistedState,outputStream);
return outputStream.toString();
```

Within the PersistedState class, there is a HashMap defined as follows:

```
private HashMap<String, SignificantEvent> significantEvents = new HashMap<String, SignificantEvent>();
```

The error seems to be suggesting that the type of the second field in the HashMap (`SignificantEvent`) is not found, but I'm taking great care not to obfuscate the SignificantEvent class when Proguarding, and the mapping output certainly seems to suggest that all the required classes and methods are present but when I disable obfuscation there is no error.

Does anyone have any idea how to configure Proguard to prevent this error? I'm at a complete loss at the moment, so any pointers would be a great help here :)

Comment: Are you keeping class and class members both for `SignificantEvent` class in your progaurd.cfg file?

Comment: I was, but that wasn't the issue, as I found out shortly after posting this question...

(see my answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there was a simple solution. I had to add the following line to my proguard.cfg:

`-keepattributes Signature`

Viola! It is clean.